# Android Bitmapfactory decoderesource which drawable will be used considering screen density

Tags: android, bitmap, screen-size

When you call:

```
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.disco);
```

Which version of "disco" will be used if I have a disco.png in each drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi and drawable-ldpi? Is it depending on the device using the code? If a hdpi - device is using the code will it use the hdpi image? I'm having trouble finding good docs on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [BitmapFactory.decodeResource and drawable\* folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756231/bitmapfactory-decoderesource-and-drawable-folders)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you provide an hdpi drawable and run this code on an hdpi device, you will get that hdpi drawable. Read this document on [how Android decides which resource to use](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch).

Comment: Thanks, quick follow-up, if you use b.getWidth() it will return the width in pixels for the given density (your case hdpi)? Thanks

Comment: Yes. You'll get the actual pixel (and not dp) width for the bitmap. Note that if you don't have an appropriate density image available, Android will attempt to scale one from a different density.