# BitmapFactory.decodeResource and drawable* folders

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable, android-resources

I am wondering if `decodeResource (Resources res, int id, BitmapFactory.Options opts)` takes into account the drawable-ldpi,mdpi,hdpi etc. folders.

I checked the source code, and it doesn't look like that, but I may be missing something.

(Generally, where are the R.drawable. resolved in Android source? I was unable to find it.)

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? and Is there any ERROR?

Comment: Some of my bitmaps are loaded via this method. I need to know how exactly decodeResource() works in the mentioned respect.

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.my_image_name);  This method returns you bitmap of image with name "my_image_name" which is in the **any of drawable** folder contained in your **res(=resource) folder**.

Comment: And if it is in more than one folder, how does it choose? That is the point. Does it choose correctly, based on the dpi of the device, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It will select proper folder as per the current Device screen size and resolution. Just you have to worry about to put all size of image in all different drawable folder.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes it takes it into account. For example if you do :

```
Resources res = getContext().getResources();
int id = R.drawable.image; 
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id);
```

The bitmap will be different if "image" is present in all of the drawables folders.
So I think using the overloaded method `decodeResource (Resources res, int id, BitmapFactory.Options opts)` will work in the same way.