# android Null pointer exception when trying to blur a bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-custom-view, blur

I have an `ImageView` which I want to blur. I am using this method for blurring: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-blur-images-efficiently-with-androids-renderscript

This is part of the layout XML file where my ImageView is initialized:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/InfoConstraint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:alpha="0.9"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@android:color/background_light" />
```

This constraint layout is also inside another constraint layout. I am then locating `backdrop` in a `custom view` with Id and extracting the `bitmap` out so I can then use the code in the above link to blur the `bitmap`. After doing so I am converting the `bitmap` back to the `ImageView`

```
backdrop = findViewById(R.id.backdrop);
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.backdrop);
Bitmap blurredBitmap = BlurBuilder.blur(context, b);
backdrop.setImageBitmap(blurredBitmap);
```

The only issue is that I am getting a null pointer exception when I call `BlurBuilder`. This is the error stack :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.sapp.BlurBuilder.blur(BlurBuilder.java:15)
        at views.customsapp$override.init(customsapp.java:73)
        at views.customsapp$override.access$dispatch(Unknown Source:67)
        at views.customsapp.init(Unknown Source:15)
        at views.customsapp$override.init$body(customsapp.java:48)
        at views.customsapp$override.access$dispatch(Unknown Source:132)
        at views.customsapp.<init>(customsapp.java:46)
            ... 33 more
```

It seem like it is not finding `backdrop` what is the problem here? I cannot figure it out. I bet something which I am not aware of is happening when I create a bitmap out of an ImageView because the backdrop is obviously there since I am calling `findViewById()` which works.

## update

This is the new exception that is being thrown when I try Anjana's answer

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:1113)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:1080)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:1030)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:991)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at views.customsapp

.init(customsapp.java:78)
    at views.customsapp.<init>(customsapp.java:48)
        ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably finds `backdrop`. The problem is here `Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.backdrop);`

You pass wrong thing to `decodeResource`. You should pass a drawable(R.drawable.bla_bla).
See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756231/bitmapfactory-decoderesource-and-drawable-folders)

Comment: but I image is not in the drawable folder. In fact, I am just trying to blur a white color background as you can see in my XML layout so the alpha value will look better.

Comment: Can you try https://github.com/MichaelEvans/EtsyBlurExample and let me know the result.

Comment: so the only solution in your opinion is to change the way I am blurring?

Comment: I just say if you want to use `BitmapFactory.decodeResource` you have to have a bitmap. If you want to blur on color it would be better you should change your way.

Answer (score 0):

Your view is not a bitmap. So it would probably return null from `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()` Therefore try using below code to create a bitmap

```
backdrop = findViewById(R.id.backdrop);
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(backdrop.getWidth(), backdrop.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);
backdrop.draw(c);
Bitmap blurredBitmap = BlurBuilder.blur(context, bmp);
backdrop.setImageBitmap(blurredBitmap)
```

Comment: this is now giving me an IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0. which makes sense since in my xml file my width and height are 0dp. but I changed those to "match_parent" and 74dp and it still is giving me the same error why is that?

Comment: Is it possible to add the error log for the new error? And try a clean build also

Comment: Just did now. does it have to do with backdrop not being draw yet? and thus no height and width are set?

Comment: If you have the layout view which contains the imageview, i don't think above is necessary. Anyway try setting a image as background also.