# getContext().getResources() from a class which doesn't inherit from Application

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to return a Bitmap from a function in a class, most of the time I will return a generated image, which works fine, but in some cases I want to return file from the resources.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11756312/391691) to [BitmapFactory.decodeResource and drawable* folders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11756231/391691) question tells me to use

```
Resources res = getContext().getResources();
int id = R.drawable.image; 
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id);
```

which I translated to

```
val res = getContext().getResources()
val errorbitmap:Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( res,  R.drawable.pm5544)
```

but of course there is a compilation error:

> Unresolved reference: getContext

Which leads us to my question:

- **On what object do I need to call `getContext()`?** *or to adress the real issue:*
- **Is there another API I should have used to get the bitmap from my resources?**

Comment: try to use Resources res = getResources(); or Resources res = getApplicationContext().getResources();

Comment: Apparently neither of those are visible to my class

Comment: can you post your activity code ?

Comment: That would be mostly irrelevant code which I cannot share anywat, but my main activity is `class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() `  and it creates this class as `object: {...}`

Comment: try this one ```  Resources res = getResources();
        int id = R.drawable.image;
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id);```

Comment: If the class is not an instance of Activity or Fragment you need to pass Context as functional paramter.

Comment: look at below answer

Comment: is it working ?

Comment: Why did someone downvote this? I was referring to possible other duplicate answers and have narrowed down the problem to calling this from outside `mainActicity`

Comment: why don't you simply pass the context in the parameters?

Comment: *why don't you simply pass the context in the parameters? – Deepak Vajpayee 2 mins ago*
That is probably what I need to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the code below from `MainActivity` you will have access to `resources`

```
val res = resources
val id = R.drawable.image
val b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id)
```

To be able to use this in your object you must either pass resources as a parameter or if you only need one image pass that as a parameter.

Comment: `val res = resources` is available from `MainActivity` but not from object

Comment: can you tell me where you are using it i.e in which class and which function ?

Comment: I made a major edit to your answer with the parameter suggestion, which is how I decided to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

> On what object do I need to call getContext()?

Use `Application` Context. You can use application context any where from your app.

Create your own `Application` class

```
public class AppApplication extends Application {

    private static AppApplication instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
    }

    public static AppApplication getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

And access application context this way:

```
Context appContext = AppApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext();
```

Now with `appContext` access your resource

**Kotlin Version:**

```
class AppApplication :Application(){

    companion object{
        private lateinit var instance:AppApplication
        fun getInstance():AppApplication{
            return instance
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
    }
}
```

Access `Application` Context

```
val applicationContext = AppApplication.getInstance().applicationContext
```

Make sure you add you Custom `AppApplication` class in `Manifest`

```
<application
    android:name=".AppApplication"
    ............
</application>
```

Using Application Context is safe as there is not `Activity` or `Fragment` Lifecycle issue

Comment: What language is this?  java?

Comment: "What language is this?" -> yes it's Java

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. A very good explanation on what I need to do to achieve what seemed as a very small task.